# How do I set managed bean property from view?

Tags: java, jsf, view, render

I have 4 JSF views and 1 managed bean. And I want to set **type** property of bean from view during render.According to this **type** value, I will have different kinds of operations.
Does anyone has suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I have 4 JSF views and 1 managed bean` , what is the scope of Bean? also explain rest of the question in bit more detail

Comment: Okey. 4 different views.Each have different values.First view should set "gold" value to type property, second one "silver" and so on.According to these customer types, I will retrieve different customer list.

Comment: JSF 1.x...BTW my scope is request scope

Answer (score 1):

On thing that comes to mind is to use four different methods, and initialize the field there to different values

```
<f:view beforePhase="#{bean.initFoo}">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..Actually I would like something like that : in the First view <f:xxxx target={#mybean.type} value='gold'/>...In the second view, I will have <f:xxxx target={#mybean.type} value='silver'/> and so on...Is there tag lik this one?Thanks